# MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle base name

Tags: spring, maven, jar, resourcebundle, properties-file

When running a jar file that i created from a maven project as such:

```
java -jar basictool.jar
```

I get this error exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
    Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com/kit/version, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(UnknownSource)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
        at com.factories.FactoryImpl.<init>(FactoryImpl.java:80)
        at com.parsers.BasicParser.<init>(BasicParser.java:32)
        at com.parsers.FileParser.<init>(FileParser.java:76)
        at com.tools.BasicTool.main(BasicTool.java:75)
    ... 5 more
```

I created the jar file by using the maven jar creation wizard:
**Right-click on project, select Export > Java > Runnable JAR file** with options

Launch configuration: **BasicTool - work**

Export destination: `C:\Users\Victor\Documents\basictool.jar`

Library handling: **Package required libraries into generated JAR**

The version.properties file is kept inside of the `src/main/resources`, as `com/kit/version.properties`.

I have checked that the version.properties file is found inside of the jar file by running:

```
jar tf basictool.jar > output.txt
```

where i find the version.properties file as such:

```
resources/com/kit/version.properties
```

I attempt to load the resource like this:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/kit/version");
```

My machine and environment specifications are as followed:
**Windows 7, Spring version: 3.7.2**.

Note:
I found many questions similar to the one i have, but the answers i have found point to the properties file being properly named or placed in the correct location. From those answers i learned that version.properties is fine, since `ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/kit/version")` will first look for version.class then version.properties by default. It will also look for version_en_US.properties before ultimately looking for the base name version.properties.
I seem to be in line with the above, since the file version.properties is in the correct location and named correctly. I also seem to be in line with what other answers have offered :(

I would also like to point out that it finds the resource just fine when i run the program from spring, which brings me to suspect that something about the jar's creation process is the cause of the problem.

And it is also important to note that the properties file is in another maven project.

I hope i offered enough/clear details. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application calls `ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/kit/version");` from with in Eclipse everything works fine.

But when you create a jar file in the way you described (export -> java -> runnable jar), the `version.properties` is placed within the jar file at `resources/com/kit/version.properties`. Mind the "**resources**" in front of the path.
If you call this jar with `java -jar basictool.jar` outside Eclipse the `version.properties` cannot be found and `java.util.MissingResourceException`is thrown.

If you change the path and call `ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/com/kit/version");` it won't work within Eclipse but `java -jar basictool.jar` will do.

It seems exporting the project from Eclipse causes the problem.

I would suggest to create the jar file to use without Eclipse with the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin).
An example can be found [here](https://www.staldal.nu/tech/2014/10/26/create-a-self-contained-jar-file-with-maven).
This plugin creates a jar file without the `resources` directory and so the call of `ResourceBundle.getBundle("com/kit/version");` works within **and** outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you! Yes this is what i ended up figuring out and did... i just forgot to write up an answer here. Nicely done :)